# Send a Message Box to a client in my Domain from C# Windows Form

Tags: c#

I have got a windows forms project than copying files and folders to clients in my domain. When copying file or copying directory process to [x]clients in my domain. I want to send it a Messagebox that says "There is a new folder or file in your [xdirectory]".

I can't do it by Messenger service because of Messenger service is does not working in XP Sp2 so I need another way for this. Maybe a client/server side application could be make. There will be a listener app in client then I will send it a `messagebox.show` code then it will show us a messagebox. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) in the client. That way you do not have to deal with remoting or listening on ports.

If you really want to communicate between the two machines you can do using [remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx), or via the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar once before.  I got most of this code from somewhere else, but I cannot remember from where.

First the Server Code:

```
public class HSTcpServer
{
    private TcpListener m_listener;
    private IPAddress m_address = IPAddress.Any;
    private int m_port;
    private bool m_listening;   
    private object m_syncRoot = new object();
    public event EventHandler<TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    public HSTcpServer(int port)
    {
        m_port = port;
    }

    public IPAddress Address
    {
        get { return m_address; }
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get { return m_port; }
    }

    public bool Listening
    {
        get { return m_listening; }
    }

    public void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (m_syncRoot)
            {
                m_listener = new TcpListener(m_address, m_port);

                // fire up the server
                m_listener.Start();

                // set listening bit
                m_listening = true;
            }

            // Enter the listening loop.
            do
            {
                Trace.Write("Looking for someone to talk to... ");

                // Wait for connection
                TcpClient newClient = m_listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                //Trace.WriteLine("Connected to new client");

                // queue a request to take care of the client
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessClient), newClient);
            }
            while (m_listening);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("SocketException: " + se.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // shut it down
            StopListening();
        }
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        if (m_listening)
        {
            lock (m_syncRoot)
            {
                // set listening bit
                m_listening = false;
                // shut it down
                m_listener.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(string message)
    {
        // Copy to a temporary variable to be thread-safe.
        EventHandler<TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs> messageReceived = MessageReceived;
        if (messageReceived != null)
            messageReceived(this, new TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
    }


    private void ProcessClient(object client)
    {
        TcpClient newClient = (TcpClient)client;
        try
        {
            // Buffer for reading data
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder clientData = new StringBuilder();

            // get the stream to talk to the client over
            using (NetworkStream ns = newClient.GetStream())
            {
                // set initial read timeout to 1 minute to allow for connection
                ns.ReadTimeout = 60000;
                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                int bytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    // read the data
                    try
                    {
                        bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            // Translate data bytes to an ASCII string and append
                            clientData.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead));
                            // decrease read timeout to 1 second now that data is 
                            // coming in
                            ns.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe)
                    {
                        // read timed out, all data has been retrieved
                        Trace.WriteLine("Read timed out: {0}", ioe.ToString());
                        bytesRead = 0;
                    }
                }
                while (bytesRead > 0);

                bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("clowns");

                // Send back a response.
                ns.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                sendMessage(clientData.ToString());
            }
        }
        finally
        {

            // stop talking to client
            if (newClient != null)
                newClient.Close();
        }
    }
}

public class TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string m_message;

    public TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs(string message)
    {
        m_message = message;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return m_message;
        }
    }
}
```

The Client Code:

```
 class HSTcpClient
{
    private TcpClient _client;
    private IPAddress _address;
    private int _port;
    private IPEndPoint _endPoint;
    private bool _disposed;

    public HSTcpClient(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        _address = address;
        _port = port;
        _endPoint = new IPEndPoint(_address, _port);
    }

    public void SendForwardedClientMessage(int senderId, int receiverId, int hsId)
    {
        SendMessage(senderId.ToString() + ":" + receiverId.ToString() + ":" + hsId.ToString());
    }

    public void SendUpdatedCGBMessage()
    {
        SendMessage("Update your CGB you clowns");
    }

    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = new TcpClient();
            _client.Connect(_endPoint);

            // Get the bytes to send for the message
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            // Get the stream to talk to the server on
            using (NetworkStream ns = _client.GetStream())
            {
                // Send message
                Trace.WriteLine("Sending message to server: " + msg);
                ns.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                // Get the response
                // Buffer to store the response bytes
                bytes = new byte[1024];

                // Display the response
                int bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                string serverResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                Trace.WriteLine("Server said: " + serverResponse);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("There was an error talking to the server: " +
                se.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_client != null)
                    _client.Close();
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Then to use, create a server variable in your form code:

```
private HSTcpServer m_server;
```

and I created a background worker thread:

```
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker hsTcpServerThread;
```

handled the DoWork event:

```
private void hsTcpServerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        m_server = new HSTcpServer(<pick your port>);
        m_server.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs>(m_server_MessageReceived);
        m_server.Listen();
    }
```

Then handle the message recieved event:

```
void m_server_MessageReceived(object sender, TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //<your code here> - e contains message details
    }
```

Then to send a message to the server:

```
HSTcpClient client = new HSTcpClient(<ip address>, <port you picked>);
            client.SendForwardedClientMessage(<message details>);
```

Hopefully I got everything in there.

Comment: void m_server_MessageReceived(object sender, TcpMessageReceivedEventArgs e)    {        //<your code here> - e contains message details    }

i dont understand this section